# What is the way to call the show action for a class with nested routes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How do you define or write a do block to call a show action with nested routes?

Am receiving a "NoMethodError in Jobs#index" where `<% @companies.jobs.each do |job| %>` raises an undefined method  `` `jobs' for #<Company::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fa4d2085e70> ``

Looking to call the show action for every company that posts a job.

**Job index controller**

```
def index
    @companies = Company.all
    @jobs = Job.all.order("created_at ASC")
end
```

**Job show controller**

```
def show
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @job = @company.jobs.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :companies do
    resources :jobs
end
```

**Rails routes**

```
company_job GET    /companies/:company_id/jobs/:id(.:format)                  jobs#show
```

**Company model**

```
has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
```

**Job model**

```
belongs_to :company, optional: true
```

**Current job index page do block**

```
<% @companies.jobs.each do |job| %>
   <%= link_to company_jobs_path(@company) %> #show action trying to call for the company posting the job
<% end %>
```

Comment: do you mean like this: `<% @jobs.each do |job| %> <%= link_to company_job_path(job.company, job) %> <% end %>`. you should consider shallow routes as well https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting

Comment: still getting a ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Jobs#index. has `missing required keys: [:company_id]`

Comment: i guess some jobs don't have a company because you made that association optional for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems here:

First, `company_jobs_path` as you have it is the index action, not the show action. `company_job_path` is the show action helper.

Second, the first argument to `link_to` needs to be the text of the link, not the `href`.

So then for a nested route you need to provide both the company and the job so in your block just:

```rb
link_to "Some text", company_job_path(@company, job)
```

Edit: actually, just noticed you have `@companies` instead of `@company` in your block wrapper. So you need to fix that too.

Comment: Tidied up the block where it points to the show action along with the arguments. But I'm receiving an `undefined method 'jobs' for nil:NilClass` for a NoMethodError on the jobs#index action

Comment: Honestly, I can't tell what you're trying to do, I think I was thrown by you showing the `show` action code where you set `@company`. But then you say you want to have a link for each company that posts a job? Seems like you need to iterate over both `@companies` and within that `each_company.jobs`, but I really can't tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: That's correct. I'm trying to iterate over each job and call the company that posted the job to show each companies show page logic